# Javascript 'onkeydown' and typewriter effect not working together?

Tags: javascript

I'm quite new to JS and I'm trying to mimic a terminal, where when the user presses enter it'll type the command out. I tried with an async function, but don't want to use that as when I try to print out a 2d array it jumbles up all the letters. With this, it seems to work fine on JSfiddle on its own, but when I put it into the onkeydown it only does 1 letter per time I press enter.

Can I make it so that it finishes typing out before continuing?

Here's the function:

```
function typeWriter() {
    if (i < txt.length) {
      var char = txt.charAt(i);
      oldOutput.innerHTML += char == '\n' ? '<br>' : char;
      i++;
      setTimeout(typeWriter, 50);
    }
   }
```

Here's the full code:

```
var speed = 50;
var message = "";
var i = 0;
var txt = "help";

var container = document.getElementById("container"); 
var command = document.getElementById("command");
var output = document.getElementById("output");

//dont get cursor lost
command.focus()

function typeWriter() {
    if (i < txt.length) {
      var char = txt.charAt(i);
      oldOutput.innerHTML += char == '\n' ? '<br>' : char;
      i++;
      setTimeout(typeWriter, 50);
    }
   }
  
command.onkeydown = function(){
    if (event.key === "Enter"){

        //declare message
        switch(command.value.toLowerCase()){
            
            case "help":
                message = help;
                break;
        }

        //create oldOutput and move cmdWrite method up
        var oldOutput = document.createElement("div");

        container.insertBefore(oldOutput, command);
        oldOutput.setAttribute("id", "oldOutput");

        //add 2d array parser here
        typeWriter(message[0][0]);

        output.innerHTML = "";

        //create oldCommand and clear command
        var oldCommand = document.createElement("div"); 
        oldOutput.setAttribute("id", "oldCommand");
        oldCommand.innerHTML = command.value;

        container.insertBefore(oldCommand, oldOutput);

        command.value = "";
    }
}



//old command
//old output

//command
//output
```

Comment: Some thoughts: if you share a JSFiddle with us, it's much easier to see what's going on.  Also, if `message` is "", then `message[0][0]` should actually throw an error (look in the console for an error) . Also `typeWriter` accepts no parameters, so don't pass one.  Finally, `txt` doesn't ever seem to be updated.

Comment: Oh haha, sorry for the confusion! Message[0][0] is "help". About the JSFiddle, I just meant if I run the typewriter command in a void, outside of command.onkeydown = function(){...} it seems to work - and with passing typeWriter parameters, that was MB, but I just tried changing it so it just has txt = "help" (no parameters being passed) and no difference. Thanks sm for the help! I'm pretty new to JS and tryna wrap my head around things is wack haha

Comment: You might be confused by the strange scope rules of JS, but that `message[0][0]` is definitely not "help" in the code you've presented.  It will throw an error.  Maybe you're not running the exact same code as you've shown.  If you're not, we can't help!

Comment: Oh haha maybe I got it wrong but what I meant to happen was that I have a file commands.js with an array:

``` 
var help = 
[
["help", "who am i?"],
["aboutme2", "who am i?2"],
["aboutme3", "who am i?3"],
["aboutme4", "who am i?4"],
["aboutme5", "who am i?5"]
];
```
and then they both go into the same HTML file so I can assign help to message, does that work? I mean in any case, no matter where the string comes from the function doesn't work

Comment: I suspect you are getting an error in the console.  Ensure you can see the console because that's where errors are reported.  If there's an error, include that in the post.  I think the key issue here is that `oldOutput` is not declared in your `typeWriter` function.  I suspect there's an error message saying exactly that.

Comment: The `var oldOutput =` statement is a LOCAL declaration that is not shared with the `typeWriter` function.

Comment: OHHH I understand!!! Thank you so much! Let me try and fiddle around, and I'll get back to you!! Thanks so much again!

Comment: Let me get this right - I should declare all variables to be used outside the functions so they're global - but if I wish to change the value of the variable within the function, will it still affect it outside?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246958/discussion-between-spook-and-user2740650).